# Using Doctrine in a service Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I use Doctrine in a class outside from the controller?

```
$event = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AtotrukisMainBundle:Event')
    ->findByCreatedBy($userId);
if (!$event) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException(
        'You have no events'
    );
}
```

The code above works perfectly in a controller, but in a service I get error: `Attempted to call method "getDoctrine" on class "Atotrukis\MainBundle\Service\EventService" in /var/www/src/Atotrukis/MainBundle/Service/EventService.php line 15.`

How do I make it work?

services.yml:

```
services:
    eventService:
        class: Atotrukis\MainBundle\Service\EventService
```

Part from the EventController:

```
public function readMyEventsAction()
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AtotrukisMainBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId());

    $userEvents = $this->get('eventService')->readUserEvents($user);

    return $this->render('AtotrukisMainBundle:Event:myEvents.html.twig', array('events' => $userEvents));
}
```

EventService.php:

```
<?php
namespace Atotrukis\MainBundle\Service;

class EventService{

    public function create(){


    }
    public function readUserEvents($userId){

        $event = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AtotrukisMainBundle:Event')
            ->findByCreatedBy($userId);
        if (!$event) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'You have no events'
            );
        }
        return $userId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it as an argument in your service declaration:

```
services:
    eventService:
        class: Atotrukis\MainBundle\Service\EventService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Then just add a constructor to your class:

```
protected $em;

public function __construct($em)
{
    $this->em = $em
}
```